# How to set Eclipse compiler level to 1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

Hi I use Eclipse 3.4 Ganymade which uses JRE 1.4/1.5 alternatively.
Now I have to use JDK1.1 for one of my application. As far as I know Eclipse uses JRE1.3 as the default level of compiler. Is there any way to work with JRE1.1. I had installed both JDK 1.1 and 1.4 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there weren't any language changes between 1.1 and 1.3, so all you have to do is set source compatibility to 1.3, "Generated .class file compatibility" to 1.1 and configure your project to use the 1.1 standard API JAR, and it should work.

**Correction:** there was one language change introduced in Java 1.2: the `strictfp` keyword. However, since it is very rarely used, it's probably something you can safely ignore. Additionally, I don't think it would result in any incompatibilities, since it only causes the VM to selectively behave like pre-1.2 VMs always did.

Comment: Actually current application uses Map Object which doesn't exist in JDK1.1. I had rework these errors using some other collection objects.
So I still need a solution

Comment: This should be solved if you, as I wrote, configure the project to use the 1.1 standard API JAR as its system library. Right click project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries

Comment: JDK1.1 has classes.zip .Will this be sufficient for compiling.Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the one you need.

Comment: +1 for ensuring compilation happens against the runtime library of a 1.1. JVM.